# Change several divs color in CSS by clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to use just CSS to achieve the same output as the below example done in JavaScript. I want to perform this in only CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="first-div" id="black"></div>
<div class="second-div" id="blue" ></div>
<div class="third-div" id="green"></div>
<div class="forth-div" id="yellow"></div>
<br>
<input type="radio" value="Black" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)">Black

<input type="radio" value="Blue" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)" >Blue

<input type="radio"value="Green" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)" >Green

<input type="radio"value="Yellow" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)">Yellow
```

**CSS**

```
div{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px;
}
.first-div{background-color:black;}
.second-div{background-color:blue;}
.third-div{background-color:green;}
.forth-div{background-color:yellow;}
```

**JavaScript**
I want to perform the same functionality without JavaScript code. just applying CSS, hacking radio button to force it to change the color of clicked div

```
function f(IncValue)
    {
        if(IncValue=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById('black').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('blue').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('green').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility="hidden";

        }
        else if(IncValue=="Blue")
        {
            document.getElementById('blue').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('black').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('green').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        else if(IncValue=="Green")
        {
            document.getElementById('green').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('black').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('blue').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility="hidden";
        }
        else if(IncValue=="Yellow")
        {
            document.getElementById('yellow').style.visibility="visible";
            document.getElementById('black').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('blue').style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('green').style.visibility="hidden";
        }


    }
```

Comment: Can your HTML be modified? By modification I don't mean addition of extra elements but just re-arrangement.

Comment: @Harry yes offcourse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By moving the all the input buttons to be before the `div` elements in the DOM and then using  general sibling selectors we can hide/show the required `div` (that corresponds to the selected color) alone.

In the below snippet, the following is what is being done:

- Whenever an `input` (radio) which has `name="clr"` is clicked, all `div` elements that are sibling of the `input` and have `class='colored-div` are hidden. I had changed the class name from the original snippet that was provided in question just to make sure that only those `div` elements are hidden. Otherwise we have to write a group of selector or use a generic `div` selector which will cause problems elsewhere (that is, other `div` present in the page will also get hidden).
- Based on the `input` (radio) that has been selected, only the `div` corresponding to the selected color is set to `visibility: visible`.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#black {
  background-color: black;
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
#green {
  background-color: green;
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
input[name="clr"]:checked ~ .colored-div {
  visibility: hidden;
}
input[value="Black"]:checked ~ #black {
  visibility: visible;
}
input[value="Blue"]:checked ~ #blue {
  visibility: visible;
}
input[value="Green"]:checked ~ #green {
  visibility: visible;
}
input[value="Yellow"]:checked ~ #yellow {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Black" name="clr">Black
<input type="radio" value="Blue" name="clr">Blue
<input type="radio" value="Green" name="clr">Green
<input type="radio" value="Yellow" name="clr">Yellow
<div class="colored-div" id="black"></div>
<div class="colored-div" id="blue"></div>
<div class="colored-div" id="green"></div>
<div class="colored-div" id="yellow"></div>
```

---

The same can be achieved by using just a single `div` element (instead of 4 `div` elements) and then changing their background color based on the selected radio button also. Below is a sample.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
}
input[value="Black"]:checked ~ .colored-div {
  background-color: black;
}
input[value="Blue"]:checked ~ .colored-div {
  background-color: blue;
}
input[value="Green"]:checked ~ .colored-div {
  background-color: green;
}
input[value="Yellow"]:checked ~ .colored-div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Black" name="clr">Black
<input type="radio" value="Blue" name="clr">Blue
<input type="radio" value="Green" name="clr">Green
<input type="radio" value="Yellow" name="clr">Yellow
<div class="colored-div"></div>
```

Comment: you have done a great work for me. the exactly what I wanted to do. Thankx

Comment: there is no doubt that you deserve the 76k rep you got

Comment: What does `~` do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **+** selector of css3 to show div. Using + , it will select all `<div>` tag that are placed immediately after `<input>` tag.

**Html** :

```
<input type="radio" value="Black" name="clr">Black
  <div class="first-div" id="black"></div>
<input type="radio" value="Blue" name="clr">Blue
  <div class="second-div" id="blue" ></div>
<input type="radio"value="Green" name="clr">Green
  <div class="third-div" id="green"></div>
<input type="radio"value="Yellow" name="clr">Yellow
  <div class="forth-div" id="yellow"></div>
```

**Css** :

```
div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px;
  display: none;
}
.first-div{background-color:black;}
.second-div{background-color:blue;}
.third-div{background-color:green;}
.forth-div{background-color:yellow;}

input[name="clr"]:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy025s72/3/).

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  margin:10px;
  display: none;
}
.first-div{background-color:black;}
.second-div{background-color:blue;}
.third-div{background-color:green;}
.forth-div{background-color:yellow;}

input[name="clr"]:checked + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" value="Black" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)">Black
  <div class="first-div" id="black"></div>
<input type="radio" value="Blue" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)" >Blue
  <div class="second-div" id="blue" ></div>
<input type="radio"value="Green" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)" >Green
  <div class="third-div" id="green"></div>
<input type="radio"value="Yellow" name="clr" onClick="f(this.value)">Yellow
  <div class="forth-div" id="yellow"></div>
```